# Default values for model fields in a Ruby on Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Model` which has fields `username, data, tags, date, votes`. I have form using `form_for` that creates a new item and puts it into the database. However, as you can guess I want the votes field to equal 0 and the date field to equal the current date when it is placed into the database. How and where would I set/apply these values to the item?

I can get it to work with hidden fields in the form but this comes with obvious issues (someone could set the `votes` field to a massive number).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a default value; zero, for votes in the db, use the automatic timestamps(`created_at`) instead of `date`, and have fields in the form only for the parameters you will set. Don't forget to protect the sensitive attributes.

```
class CreateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :models do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.text :data
      t.string :tags
      t.integer :votes, :default => 0

      t.timestamps # this will give you two automatic fields: created_at and updated_at
    end
  end
  …
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :votes #so that it cannot be set by mass assignment
  …
end
```

Comment: +1 for putting data-integrity business logic in the DB instead of the model.

Comment: +1. The [community-driven Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#migrations) also recommends enforcing default values in the migrations instead of in the application layer.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that DB constraints approach is one of the best.
But it is not always possible to be used. Assume there is a single table inheritance and  different default value per child model is required.
Than I recommend to put this into a model. Let me give an example:

```
class ChildModel < Model
  after_initialize :set_defaults
  private
  def set_defaults
    self.allowed_votes_per_person = 10 if self.new_record?
  end 
end
```

By using :after_initialize callback there is no need to create and remember to call :new_default like methods and so on. 
It sets required default values, but stays unobtrusive from the interface point of view when one calls ChildModel.new

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to set the default values on the create action on the controller.

```
@model = Model.new(params[:model])
@model.votes = 1
@model.date = Time.now
@model.save
```

Another way, and more clean too, is to create a method in the Model.

```
class Model

def new_default(model)
  model = Model.new(model)
  model.votes = 1
  model.date = Time.now
end
```

So in you controller you will have:

```
@model = Model.new_default(params[:model])

if @model.save
   render something
else
   render something_else
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a screencast on protecting attributes:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment

Rails models come with automatic timestamping by default, created_at and updated_at fields are the names for the attributes. You don't have to worry about setting them, that will rails handle for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no privilage to comment to others answers yet but have a related question to Nerian, so am posting this. I am using a code like

```
before_create : create_rest
def create_rest
  15.times do
    self.players.build({:name => Rnlist.order("rand()").first.raname,
                        :cost => 140+rand(40),
                        :coop => rand(3)})
  end
end
```

in the model user.rb. This code works perfectly fine and creates 15 players with different names, etc. However if I'm trying to put the attributes into the player model the way you suggest (using create method in the players_controller), the self.players.build method creates 15 players with empty attributes without giving any error. I thought that trying the code with new method instead of create in players_controller could solve this but the result is the same. Can self.players.build method cause the problem? I checked the [Ruby API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for others.build() and also [Vinhboy.com blog](http://vinhboy.com/blog/2009/01/15/rails-new-vs-build/), but couldn't solve this issue.